# Provide simple axioms to Z3

Tags: z3

Is there a way to tell Z3 that a logical axiom might be applicable in a situation?
For example, P(x) ==> \exists x P(x) is always valid. But if P is complicated enough, then Z3 can get confused and say unknown.

```
(declare-const size Int)
(declare-const h (Array Int Int))
(assert  (forall ((j Int) (k Int)) (=> (and (<= 0 k) (< k size) (<= 0 j) (< j size) (not (= k j))) (not (= (select h j) (select h k))))))
(assert (not (exists ((g (Array Int Int))) (forall ((j Int) (k Int)) (=> (and (<= 0 k) (< k size) (<= 0 j) (< j size) (not (= k j))) (not (= (select g j) (select g k))))))))
(check-sat)
```

The first assertion says that h is an array that maps distinct integers from 0..size-1 to distinct integers. And the second assertion says that such an array cannot exist.
Can simple valid axioms such as P(x) ==> \exists x P(x) be provided in SMT files to help Z3? It might be that I have misunderstood what is happening in this example. But according to my limited understanding, Z3 might succeed in proving that the formula is unsat if it instantiates the axiom I mentioned.

Comment: Do you (de)activate MBQI? What about AUTO_CONFIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a triggering problem, i.e., Z3 does not instantiate the existentially quantified axiom (and probably also not the universally quantified one). Have a look at the following simplified example:

```
(set-option :AUTO_CONFIG false)
(set-option :SMT.MBQI false)

(declare-fun f (Int) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x Int))
  (=> (<= 0 x) (f x))
))

(assert (not (exists ((x Int))
  (=> (<= 0 x) (f x))
)))

; (assert (f -10))

(check-sat)
```

Z3 (version 4.3.2, 64 bit, build hashcode 96f4606a7f2d) reports `unknown`, but if you uncomment the last assertion, that it reports `unsat`. I thus assume that the pattern that Z3 infers for both axioms is `:pattern ((f x))`, which means, that `f x` must syntactically occur before the axioms can be instantiated.

You can read more about [quantifier patterns](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28) in the z3 guide.

Comment: Thanks! This clears things. I believe if I want to do reasoning with quantified formulas, never instantiating them, then I will have this trouble.